# Cannot create new php project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using Zend Eclipse for PHP developers version 3.2.0.
I have just created a new workspace for an existing local project but Eclipse keeps coming up with an error when I try to create the project.

An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org.eclipse.php.internal.server.core.manager.ServersManager.isEmptyServer(Lorg/eclipse/php/internal/server/core/Server;)Z

I have another workspace with a project on it which works fine, it just won't let me create a new project in a new workspace.

Anyone know what is going on?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add server to your eclipse before create a new php project ?

Comment: Hi @hurricane, I have never needed to do that before. I added a server but still get the same error when adding a new project.